# 3.95 TFT LCD SPI or parallel interface

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, esp8266, spi

I would like to get one information about this TFT LCD module . This particular module works with parallel interface with arduino mega and uno.

I am trying to get rid of arduino in my project and use esp8266 itself. I have this module http://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-5-inch-TFT-Touch-LCD-Screen-Display-Module-For-Arduino-UNO-R3-HIGH-QUALITY-Free/1854595985.html

This has only the parallel interface pins mentioned which requires around more than 10 pins to make it work. Is there any possibility that there is an SPI interface supported for this one by  making use of any of the existing pins for the parallel interface.

I don't think so but still can someone confirm that. If so I need to get SPI interface ready TFT LCDs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. The interface used by the chip is normally hard wired either in the connections to the Chip On Glass or in the connections of the shield (most commonly the former) and as such cannot really be changed.

You will need to either use a TFT screen that has the interface already set to SPI (and there are many) or use some form of SPI I/O expander to provide enough I/O pins to drive a parallel display.

Note that using SPI to communicate with a screen makes the screen updates considerably slower than using a parallel interface. The bigger the screen the slower it gets.